# How to add image instead of text in Content Menu Item in Orchard 1.7.1

Tags: c#, razor, orchardcms-1.7

I have read and try to reproduce steps from this question/answer [How to extend Orchard navigation module to add images to menu items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450474/how-to-extend-orchard-navigation-module-to-add-images-to-menu-items)

1. Have created MenuImagePart with "Image" Content Picker field
2. Have added this part to "Content Menu Item"
3. Changed code in MenuItemLink-ContentMenuItem.cshtml

But got next error:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/86009304/MenuImagePart.png

```
@using Orchard.Utility.Extensions;
@using System.Dynamic
@{

/* Getting the menu content item
***************************************************************/

var menu = Model.Content.ContentItem;

/* Creating a unique CSS class name based on the menu item
***************************************************************/

// !!! for some reason the following code throws: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'HtmlClassify'
//string test = menu.ContentType.HtmlClassify();
string cssPrefix = Orchard.Utility.Extensions.StringExtensions.HtmlClassify(menu.ContentType);
var uniqueCSSClassName = cssPrefix + '-' + Model.Menu.MenuName;
/* Adds the normal and hovered styles to the html if any
***************************************************************/
if (menu.MenuImagePart != null)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(menu.MenuImagePart.Image.Url))
    {
    using(Script.Head()){
    <style>
        .@uniqueCSSClassName {
            background-image: url('@Href(menu.MenuImagePart.Image.Url)');
            width: @{@menu.MenuImagePart.Image.Width}px;
            height: @{@menu.MenuImagePart.Image.Height}px;
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
    }
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(menu.MenuImagePart.HoverImage.Url))
    {
    using(Script.Head()){
    <style>
        .@uniqueCSSClassName:hover {
            background-image: url('@Href(menu.MenuImagePart.HoverImage.Url)');
            width: @{@menu.MenuImagePart.HoverImage.Width}px;
            height: @{@menu.MenuImagePart.HoverImage.Height}px;
        }
    </style>    
    }
    }
}
}    
<a class="@uniqueCSSClassName" href="@Model.Href">@Model.Text</a>
```

What I done wrong and how should I create this image to add to newly created "Content Menu Item"?

Answer (score 0):

You have a contentpicker field on there, you want a mediapickerfield (if you are Orchard 1.6).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm using 1.7.1

Comment: Then you want to use the MediaGalleryField (I believe). ContentPickerField is wrong